# Oracle: forcing parallelism over index search

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, indexing

[image]

I would like to use parallel execution on LET_TESTATE_LETTURE without forcing the full table scan, I want to use force the parallelism on index.

How can I solve?

```
alter session enable parallel dml;  

CREATE TABLE netatemp.let_testate_letture1
AS
   SELECT /* parallel(tele 32) full(tele) */
         tele.TELE_DATA_LETTURA,
         tele.tele_storico_id
     FROM let_testate_letture tele
    WHERE     tele.prov_provenienza_lettura_id = '*1ENI01BCAMBIO'
          AND tele.spwkf_stato_pubblico_id != '*1UNICOANN';


Size    56,1 GB
Number Extents  1.081

OWNER   SIUMETERING
TABLE_NAME  LET_TESTATE_LETTURE
TABLESPACE_NAME SIUMETERING_DATITD
CLUSTER_NAME    
IOT_NAME    
STATUS  VALID
PCT_FREE    10
PCT_USED    
INI_TRANS   30
MAX_TRANS   255
INITIAL_EXTENT  80 KB
NEXT_EXTENT 1 MB
MIN_EXTENTS 1
MAX_EXTENTS 2.147.483.645
PCT_INCREASE    
FREELISTS   
FREELIST_GROUPS 
LOGGING YES
BACKED_UP   N
NUM_ROWS    456.635.338
BLOCKS  3.340.120
EMPTY_BLOCKS    0
AVG_SPACE   0
CHAIN_CNT   0
AVG_ROW_LEN 385
AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS   0
NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS 0
DEGREE  1
INSTANCES   1
CACHE   N
TABLE_LOCK  ENABLED
SAMPLE_SIZE 456.635.338
LAST_ANALYZED   29/12/2012 13:03:15
PARTITIONED NO
IOT_TYPE    
TEMPORARY   N
SECONDARY   N
NESTED  NO
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
CELL_FLASH_CACHE    DEFAULT
ROW_MOVEMENT    DISABLED
GLOBAL_STATS    YES
USER_STATS  NO
DURATION    
SKIP_CORRUPT    DISABLED
MONITORING  YES
CLUSTER_OWNER   
DEPENDENCIES    DISABLED
COMPRESSION ENABLED
COMPRESS_FOR    OLTP
DROPPED NO
READ_ONLY   NO
SEGMENT_CREATED YES
RESULT_CACHE    DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to alter the index to parallel. ie

```
alter index xxx parallel;
```

or

```
alter index xxx parallel <n>;
```

as the parallel hint only applies to tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
/*+ parallel_index(tele, let_tele_letb_prov_fk_idx, 32) */
```

Notice the "+" after the asterisk. Without it Oracle will ignore the hint.

Also, you may want to create the table in parallel as well depending on the nr of rows returned, like:

```
CREATE TABLE netatemp.let_testate_letture1 parallel 32 as
select /*+ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You posted a lot of useful information, which is very refreshing.  So in addition to answering your question, I can provide
other advice for improving performance:

1. Statement-level hint.
   Since you are on 11gR2 (based on the existence of the column `SEGMENT_CREATED`), you should use a
   [statement-level parallel hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#CHDGEGFI), instead of an object-level.  Use `/*+ parallel(32) */`, and then Oracle will parallelize everything in the query, regardless of the access method or the alias names.
2. Old stats or old data?
   Last Analyzed on 2012-12-29 seems kind of old.  If your table is very active, then you should re-gather statistics.  If it really doesn't change very often, you may want to consider re-creating it, ordered by `prov_provenienza_lettura_id`.  That may significantly improve the performance of your index.  Although it could decrease performance of other indexes.
3. Compression.
   Your table uses compression, but is your index also compressed?  If you really have 9 million entries for the same value, index compression could save a huge amount of space, and make index reads much faster.  Also, a bitmap index may be a good fit here.
4. Full table scans.
   The optimizer thinks you're going to read about 2% of your rows.  Even 2% may be enough to warrant a full table scan, depending on things such as the clustering factor.  You may not want to try to force a specific access method - first let Oracle try to pick.  If Oracle gets it wrong, then you should try to help it by providing more useful information, such as better statistics and maybe a histogram.

The advice from DazzaL and Ronnis should also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask you how can I force Oracle to calculate an histogram and update stats? (it's 11g)

Comment: @Gik25: `exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(<schema name?>, 'LET_TESTATE_LETTURE', method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO, FOR COLUMNS PROV_PROVENIENZA_LETTURA_ID SIZE 254');`  Although you might want to try it first without the `method_opt`, I'm not sure if that will necessarily help.  Also, since this table is so large you may want to gather stats in parallel, which you could do by adding a parameter like `degree => dbms_stats.auto_degree`.